# Javascript won't display?

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

This is probably a silly question, but for some reason I can't get Javascript to display on my pages. I'm trying it on both notepad and Dreamweaver, and testing them using localhost in XAMP but can't get it to display to test it.

I've tried it also with some very basic code just to see if it works, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

now = new Data();
localtime = now.toString();
utctime = now.toGMTSTring();

document.write("<b>Local Time:</b> " + localtime + "<br />");
document.write("<b>UTC Time:</b> " + utctime + "<br />");

hours = now.getHours();
mins = now.getMinutes();
secs = now.getSeconds();

document.write("<h1>");
document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs);
document.write("</h1>");
```

but getting nothing at the moment, just a HTML header i've put in. I was hoping somebody had a suggestion anyway.

Comment: Though "document.write()" is pretty ugly, that should work unless something else on the page is broken.  Do you see JavaScript errors in the console (or in FireBug)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
now = new Data();
```

Is that supposed to be `new Date()`? If so, it's going to throw a ReferenceError and stop your code.

Comment: I assumed that was a typo, but that sure would cause a problem :-)

Comment: Yeh its supposed to be date, sorry typing error, it doesn't work with it as Date.

Comment: @snakespan: there is another typo on the utctime line. With that one corrected, does it work?

Comment: appreciate your help, turns out it was my typing errors, on both the code above and my original code (which was too long to post here), though the code above was lifted from a book, so they must have had printing errors too :)

Comment: @snakespan - no printing errors, you can't copy/paste from a hardcopy book, it's your reading and typing error bro.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var now = new Date();
var localtime = now.toString();
//var utctime = now.toGMTSTring();

document.write("<b>Local Time:</b> " + localtime + "<br />");
//document.write("<b>UTC Time:</b> " + utctime + "<br />");

var hours = now.getHours();
var mins = now.getMinutes();
var secs = now.getSeconds();

document.write("<h1>");
document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs);
document.write("</h1>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug. I typed

```
now = new Data();
```

in the console, and I got:

> ReferenceError: Data is not defined

Then,

```
utctime = now.toGMTSTring();
```

yields this response:

> TypeError: now.toGMTSTring is not a function

Final observation: use `var` when declaring your variables. Most browsers will work with it, but I've had a hard time tracing this error when a script turned out to refuse to work in IE (don't remember which version).